# what is wrong when training an autoencoder on mnist dataset with caffe?

Tags: caffe, autoencoder, nvidia-digits

I want to use mnist dataset to train a simple autoencoder in caffe and with nvidia-digits.

I have:
caffe: 0.16.4
DIGITS: 5.1
python 2.7

I use the structure provided here:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/mnist_autoencoder.prototxt

Then I face 2 problems:

- When I use the provided structure I get this error:

  ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "digits/scheduler.py", line 512, in run_task
       task.run(resources)
     File "digits/task.py", line 189, in run
       self.before_run()
     File "digits/model/tasks/caffe_train.py", line 220, in before_run
       self.save_files_generic()
     File "digits/model/tasks/caffe_train.py", line 665, in save_files_generic
       'cannot specify two val image data layers'
   AssertionError: cannot specify two val image data layers
  ```
- when I remove the layer for ''test-on-test'', I get a bad result like this:
  https://screenshots.firefox.com/8hwLmSmEP2CeiyQP/localhost

What is the problem??

Answer (score 1):

The first problem occurs because the `.prototxt` has two layers with name `data` and `TEST` phase. The first layer that uses `data`, *i.e.* `flatdata`, does not know which *data* to use (the *test-to-train* or *test-to-test*). That's why when you remove one of the data layers with TEST phase, the error does not happen. **Edit**: I've checked the solver file and it has a `test_stage` parameter that should switch between the test files, but it's clearly not working in your case.

The second problem is a little more difficult to solve. My knowledge in autoencoders is limited. It seems your euclidean loss changes very little during your iterations; I would check the base learning rate in your `solver.prototxt` and decrease it. Check how the losses fluctuate.

Besides that, for the epochs/iterations that achieved a low error, have you checked the output data/images? Do they make sense?